# Why does authentication behave differently between IIS7 and IIS8 Express

Tags: debugging, authentication, iis-7, iis-express

I have a mostly empty MVC4 project running on windows 7 using VS2012. In my `web.config` I have a reference to an external file that configures my authentication mode. I've tried removing this and declaring the mode inline but it produces the same result. In the `web.config` there's this line

```
<authentication configSource="Authentication.config" />
```

In the `Authentication.config` file there's these lines:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".AuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="180" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

When I access the project in IIS7 I am correctly redirected to `/Account/LogOn` when I try to access this through the IIS8 Express built into to Visual Studio 2012 this option appears to be ignored.